# Click in success ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, jquery-events

I have question about trigger event in success **ajax.**

I need to trigger the click to an `<a>` tag after AJAX call in `[success: function(res){}]`, but for some reason it doesn't want to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    function popUpPaypal(){
        $j.ajax({
            url: '<?= Mage::getBaseUrl()?>xpayment/index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function(res){
              $j('#payPalRedirect').attr('href','https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey='+res+'&expType=mini');
          //the link are change but i want call click event of $j("payPalRedirect");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to redirect the user to the new page? Because simulating click events on links doesn't redirect the user, so that would not be the solution to your problem.

Comment: no, $j("#payPalRedirect") is call a popup when i click on that, dude :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you use trigger event for this case.

$j = jQuery.noConflict();

```
function popUpPaypal(){
    $j.ajax({<br/>
        url: '<?= Mage::getBaseUrl()?>xpayment/index',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function(res){
          $j('#payPalRedirect').attr('href','https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey='+res+'&expType=mini');

        **$('#payPalRedirect').trigger('click');**
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just changed the url of the anchor tag
You have to trigger its click also

See [Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    function popUpPaypal(){
        $j.ajax({
            url: '<?= Mage::getBaseUrl()?>xpayment/index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function(res){
              $j('#payPalRedirect').attr('href','https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey='+res+'&expType=mini');
          //the link are change but i want call click event of $j("payPalRedirect");
            //code for triggering click
             $j('#payPalRedirect').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If click is not working you can use basic JavaScript

```
window.location = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey='+res+'&expType=mini';
```

Comment: yeah :D i try many event but don't know how to firing in success: function(res){}

Comment: @Long: I'm pretty sure the click event is fired, but the link might not respond to that. Without more information (i.e. how exactly the popup is bound to the link) we can't really help you.

Comment: <a id="payPalRedirect" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-3P78939660878441R&expType=mini" target="_blank">Complete PayPal Payment</a>

when i click in a tag, it throw me a popup window and when i close it i have

<script>
    var returnFromPayPal = function () {
        alert("Returned from PayPal");
    }
    var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({ trigger: 'payPalRedirect', expType: 'mini', callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal' });
</script>

to show me are that popup close or not, so i need a click in a tag, not a new window

Comment: In that case you have to create a new window using var = windowReference = window.open("url"); then you can do above work using windowReference variable.